# Vaadin: How to remove item from DB container grid

Tags: vaadin

How do I remove a row from a container/item/grid/db/entity/bean/class/object/ID?

Also, what's the difference between all these? 
Everyone seems to say these as if they were interchangeable. 
Can I get a simple explanation of how these all work together? 
I've been through dozens of youtube videos and tutorials, but I still can't see the big picture.

Simple task: Delete one row from a grid.

But then it starts getting bigger and more complex with nested beanitem container property field entities and I just can't make sense of it.

Thank you for all of your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The **[Grid](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html)**, [Table](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html) or any other [Vaadin Component](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html) used to present set of data use some implementation of the **[Container](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Container.html)** to store your data. A `Component` is a part of your User Interface, the `<div>` in your `DOM` which is seen by your end user. The [Vaadin Containers](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html) contains your **objects**. The most widely used containers are:

- `IndexedContainer` - default container for `Grid` and `Table`. You usually add **items** by calling [addItem](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Container.html#addItem%28%29) method on either container or related component. The disadvantage of using this type of container is that you are usually obligated to set appropriate [properties](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Property.html) (think of columns) on both items and the container itself,
- `BeanContainer` - is able to receive Java objects that follows [JavaBean](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/JavaBeans) convention. Thus it is able to automatically infer properties of your component,
- `SQLContainer` - contains data stored in database. Constructed using SQL query. Can be setup to automatically update your database based on changes made by user in UI.

### Items and IDs

Adding single items to some containers may look a bit complicated. There are a few ways to do this. They are described very well on a [Vaadin website](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html). Basically the ID is an unique object that you use to access corresponding `Item`. The `Item` is represents the single row in your component. Every `Item` have properties. You can access and make changes to your items in container using their IDs i.e.

```
table.getItem("uniqueId");
```

Usually, you don't operate directly on containers. The components expose basic `Container` interface methods via their API. In example implementation of [AbstractSelect.getItem()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractSelect.html#getItem%28java.lang.Object%29) component currently (Vaadin 7.5.9):

```
protected Container items;
public Item getItem(Object itemId) {
    return items.getItem(itemId);
}
```

(`AbstractSelect` is a super class of other Vaadin components like `Table` and `Grid`)

It gets more complicated with properties of the items. Every `Item` have some properties (columns). And every [Property](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Property.html) has its corresponding ID. Using property ID you can access the value of the item in the specific column. The following code presents above - it adds one item with one property and sets its value:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.addContainerProperty("column1", String.class, "defaultValue");
Item item = table.addItem("uniqueId");
item.getItemProperty("column1").setValue("Black Friday");
```

Notice that it is perfectly safe to use [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) literals as IDs since underneath they are compared using [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)